# Using CSS gradient with background image in buttons

Tags: css

There is example below :

```
.btn
{
 color:white;
 border:solid 1px navy;
 cursor:pointer;
 font-weight:bold;
 text-align:center;
 padding-left:26px;
 text-align:left;
 width:120px;
 height:25px;
 display:inline-block;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #2c539e 0%, #2c539e 100%);
}
.btn:hover
{
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #dff2fc 0%, #d7effc 48%, #bde4fa 80%, #abddf8 100%);
 border:1px solid #3C7FB1;
 color:Black;
}
```

Now, how to put image too, but different image for each button?

```
<input type="button" value="Save" class="btn" /><br> <!-- there's need save.png -->
<input type="button" value="Cancel" class="btn" /> <!-- there's need cancel.png -->
```

I know for combining gradient with image goes like bellow code :

```
background: url(save.png) 5px center no-repeat, -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #2c539e 0%, #2c539e 100%);
```

But, how to use `btn` class and different image for each button?

**EDIT :**
Well, I wasn't specific in my question (my bad)...
In example, above, using `btn` class buttons are some dark blue gradient color, on hover they are some light blue gradient color.
But, in any button I need, on left side different image, like icon.

```
+-----------+
| X Save    |
+-----------+
```

where X is image 16x16. That "icon" must be in the front of gradient background from css.

**EDIT 2 :**
Or just to forget gradient background and use simple color? :-/

Comment: You can use more than one class you know.

Comment: I don't understand ... create class for each button? can You post some example, please... thx

Comment: If you want each button to look different then yes.

Comment: I think, unfortunately, You are right, or to do what I wrote in **Edit2**... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, like @Paulie_D wrote, this isn't possible.

So, if I need different background image for each button, combining with gradient background, each button need his own css.

```css
.btn
  {
    color:white;
    border:solid 1px navy;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    padding-left:26px;
    text-align:left;
    width:120px;
    height:25px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom:5px;
  }
  .btn:hover
  {
    border:1px solid #3C7FB1;
    color:Black;
  }
  .save
  {
    background: url(http://cdn.makeuseof.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/save.png?22f766) no-repeat 5px center/16px 16px, -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #2c539e 0%, #2c539e 100%);
  }
  .save:hover
  {
    background: url(http://cdn.makeuseof.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/save.png?22f766) no-repeat 5px center/16px 16px, -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #dff2fc 0%, #d7effc 48%, #bde4fa 80%, #abddf8 100%);
  }
  .cancel
  {
    background: url(http://www.clker.com/cliparts/e/5/c/c/13695034571623408465ip_icon_02_cancel-md.png) no-repeat 5px center/16px 16px, -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #2c539e 0%, #2c539e 100%);
  }
  .cancel:hover
  {
    background: url(http://www.clker.com/cliparts/e/5/c/c/13695034571623408465ip_icon_02_cancel-md.png) no-repeat 5px center/16px 16px, -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #dff2fc 0%, #d7effc 48%, #bde4fa 80%, #abddf8 100%);
  }
```

```html
<input type="button" class="save btn" value="Save" /><br>
<input type="button" class="cancel btn" value="Cancel" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another class in your inputs(with image you want):

```
<input type="button" value="Save" class="btn save" />
<input type="button" value="Cancel" class="btn cancel" />
```

and in css

```
.save {
  background-image: url(save img);
}

.cancel {
  background-image: url(cancel img);
}
```

Comment: This not working with `gradient background` of `btn` class ... image will not appear.